# Curious about color code for matplotlib colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I was wondering what this `1.` means in the color code of a matplotlib colormap. These are some *viridis* colors:

```
[[ 0.267004  0.004874  0.329415  1.      ]
 [ 0.278826  0.17549   0.483397  1.      ]
 [ 0.229739  0.322361  0.545706  1.      ]
 [ 0.172719  0.448791  0.557885  1.      ]
 [ 0.127568  0.566949  0.550556  1.      ]
 [ 0.157851  0.683765  0.501686  1.      ]
 [ 0.369214  0.788888  0.382914  1.      ]
 [ 0.678489  0.863742  0.189503  1.      ]
 [ 0.993248  0.906157  0.143936  1.      ]]
```

Generated with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np

colors = plt.get_cmap('viridis')(np.linspace(0, 1.0, 9))
print colors
```

The first three numbers of the sublists are obviously just RGB values, but can someone help with the `1.` regarding its function.

N.B.: I'm not having any errors, as the title says, I'm just curious about it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `1.0` stands for *alpha* or the *opaqueness* of the colors. That is the `alpha` parameter in functions like [`.to_rgba(arg, alpha=None)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.to_rgba).